# GDI printing not triggering printer

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, visual-c++, gdi+

I am writing a printing application in c#. In my application i done following steps

- Created Device context (hdc)
- Created and started Document StartDoc
- Created and Started Page StartPage
- Assigned images to context
- called BitBlt and assigned conext to right hdc
- EndPage(hdc)
- EndDoc(hdc)

After all these steps, printing is not trigered. I want to ask that printing should be trigered itself
after all these steps or i need to trigger it by some other method?

Following is source code where CardPrinterLib is class in which i imported gdi32.dll and mapped its function

```
IntPtr hdc = IntPtr.Zero;
hdc = CardPrinterLib.CreateDC(null, ps.PrinterName, null, IntPtr.Zero);


CardPrinterLib.DOCINFO docinfo = new CardPrinterLib.DOCINFO();

docinfo.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(docinfo);
docinfo.pDocName = "PrinterTest";
docinfo.pOutputFile = null;
docinfo.pDataType = null;
docinfo.fwType = 0;

 if (CardPrinterLib.StartDoc(hdc, ref docinfo) > 0)
      {                        
          if (CardPrinterLib.StartPage(hdc) > 0)
             {
                Bitmap bmpFrontCard = (Bitmap)imgFrontCard;
                Graphics grFrontCard = this.CreateGraphics();
                IntPtr dcFrontCard = grFrontCard.GetHdc();
                IntPtr chdcFrontCard = CardPrinterLib.CreateCompatibleDC(dcFrontCard);
                CardPrinterLib.SelectObject(chdcFrontCard, bmpFrontCard.GetHbitmap());
                Graphics ghdcFrontCard = Graphics.FromHdc(chdcFrontCard);
                grFrontCard.ReleaseHdc(dcFrontCard);
                IntPtr hhdcFrontCard = ghdcFrontCard.GetHdc();

                bool resultFrontCard = CardPrinterLib.BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 994, 624, hhdcFrontCard, 0, 0, 13369376);

                 CardPrinterLib.EndPage(hdc);

              }                                      
CardPrinterLib.EndDoc(hdc);                   
CardPrinterLib.DeleteDC(hdc);
```

Comment: That should be enough. How do you create the DC? Are you checking that all functions return with success? Please post some code.

Comment: yes of all of calls are returning true, i am changing question with code

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to hack this code with pinvoke.  Use the .NET PrintDocument class.

Comment: Actually this application is integrated with a card printer(encode + print), its sdk is in c++. Regardless of that API i just want to confirm that either this code will work for any other printer or there is some mistake

Comment: I tried with .Net PrintDocument as well. After this code if i write PrintDocument.Print() then it prints document in next attempt not in same flow.